# integral of $\,x/\ln(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm tried to integrate this integral without any success using integration by parts and substitution.  $$\int_0^1\int_{e^y}^e \frac{x}{\ln x} dx dy$$
Does this integral require some other technique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $R=\{(x,y):0\le y\le 1,\, e^y\le x\le e\}$. Then you can check that $R=\{(x,y):1\le x\le e,\, 0\le y\le\ln x\}$. So we get

$$\int_0^1 \int_{e^y}^e \frac{x}{\ln x} dxdy=\iint_R \frac{x}{\ln x}dA=\int_1^e\int_0^{\ln x} \frac{x}{\ln x} dydx=\int _1^e xdx=\frac{e^2-1}{2}.$$

Comment: (+1) this is the right approach to the problem which is easier to integrate.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, and in order to make things clearer **perhaps**, interchange $\;x\leftrightarrow y\;$:

$$I:=\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_{e^x}^e\frac y{\log y}dydx$$

Next, change order of integration:

$$I=\int\limits_1^e\int\limits_0^{\log y}\frac y{\log y}dxdy=\int\limits_1^e ydy=\frac12(e^2-1)$$

Comment: (+1) Interchanging the order of integration makes the problem easier.

Answer (score 4):

Let $u = \ln{x}$. Then $du = \frac{dx}{x}$; now using that $x = e^u$, we can rearrange this to state that $e^u du = dx$. Hence

$$\int \frac{x}{\ln{x}} dx = \int \frac{e^u}{u} e^u du = \int \frac{e^{2u}}{u} du$$

This can then be expressed in terms of the [exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

Comment: @AndréNicolas Apparently I'm rather upside down tonight.

Comment: @TBongers I had tried the substitution u = ln x but had ended up with the exponential integral you mentioned, which did not help since we haven't learnt about the exponential integral. I've edited the question to provide details of the definite integral I'm trying to determine.

Comment: @EggHead Have you tried changing the order of integration?

Comment: @TBongers Thx. After a night's sleep, I realized that was one of the things I didn't not try...